# How to hide the tabs and make them reappear in Android versions < 3?

Tags: java, android, android-view

I want to hide tabs on the screen tap and make them reappear on another screen tap. I've seen this in plenty applications so this should be possible. I can hide them successfully using `setvisibility = VIEW.GONE`. I tried this:

```
private OnClickListener tabClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            v.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        }
        else if(v.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            v.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        }
    }
};
```

This is the xml code:

`enter code here`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="this is a tab" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="this is another tab" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="this is a third tab" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="this is a fourth tab" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

This is the java code:

```
public class TabWorkEntryActivity extends TabActivity {


//hide tabs
private OnClickListener tabClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            v.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
        } else {
            v.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        }
    }
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.tabworkentry);

TabHost  mTabHost = getTabHost();
//get width of the display
  Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
  int width = display.getWidth();

   mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("top10").setIndicator("Top        10").setContent(R.id.textview1));
                 mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("billable").setIndicator("Billable").setContent(R.id.textview2));
   mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("product").setIndicator("Product").setContent(R.id.textview3));
  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("regular").setIndicator("Regular").setContent(R.id.textview4));

  mTabHost.setCurrentTab(3);

  mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((width/9)*2),50));
  mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(new
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((width/9)*2),50));
  mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setLayoutParams(new
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((width/9)*2),50));
  mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setLayoutParams(new
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((width/9)*2),50));
```

// Somewhere else in your code...
        mTabHost.setOnClickListener( tabClickListener );
    }
    }

For some reason, this code isn't working. Could someone please help.

Comment: Hey Harsh, you should copy and paste your code to your original post, not to other peoples answers. :)

Comment: Then leave a comment on my post (and others if you choose) letting me know that you've made a change.

Comment: This is my original post I guess. I left a comment on your post but I copied my code to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `OnClickListener` in your activity's `onCreate` method.

```
v.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
```

You can also try using `View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE` to hide the views.

---

### Edit:

This is the code that I would use:

```
private OnClickListener tabClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            v.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
        } else {
            v.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh I did. I'm sorry I didn't paste it here. I believe it's mTabHost.setOnClickListener( tabClickListener ); or is it v.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);? v is local object to method onClick right. It still didn't work.

Comment: Try using `View.INVISIBLE` to hide the tabs instead of `View.GONE`.

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't work. Actually, as I've mentioned in the question, hiding isn't an issue. The problem is to make them reappear. I was wondering if the code I wrote inside the onClick function is correct and sufficient to make the tabs reappear?

Comment: Java doesn't have functions. Everything is a *method*.

Comment: There is a difference between *invisible* and *gone*. `View.GONE` takes no space (for layout purposes). `View.INVISIBLE` still takes the same amount of space... but is just not displayed on the screen. My thinking was that since `View.GONE` takes no space, there is no space where the "click" can be received. This is also confirmed by the fact that your code works *before* you click for the first time, but not *after*. Are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: See my updated post for the code that I would use. Let me know if it works for you. (Note that I got rid of the `else if` and replaced it with an `else`).

Comment: Didn't work! May be 'v.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );' isn't the right approach to make them reappear.

Comment: Add your XML layout at the end of your original post. Also let us know what exactly your "view" is in this case and show us how you inflate it (using an inflater, setContentView + findViewById, etc.). It could be an issue regarding focusability/clickability or something.

Comment: Here is an idea. Have your tab view be a global (private instance) variable and just ignore the argument `v` that is passed to `onClick`. Maybe that will work...

Comment: I've copied the xml code. And I'm using setContentView + findViewById

Comment: Actually I realized that I'm using nested tabs which might be causing a problem. Could you tell me what exactly 'v' from 'View v' refers to. Because I already have tabs at the bottom which I want to keep visible. I only want the tabs that appear above them to go away and reappear.

Comment: the `v` passed to `onClick` is the view that was clicked. So perhaps the wrong view is being clicked? i.e. maybe the nested tabs is preventing the correct view from having focus/getting clicked?

Comment: Okay so again, I have nested tabs, the main (outer) tabs as activities are always there at the bottom. Above that are the inner tabs as views. Once clicked on the screen (above) both the layers of tabs, only the tabs above the main tabs disappear. I think may be they don't reappear because tabs at the bottom still make VISIBILITY == VISIBLE condition true every time. Is it?

Comment: Oh! I guess the view being passed is the whole framed layout due to which when I added a few more things to layout they disappear too. How do I pass the view that only consists of the tabwidget?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Actionbar Sherlock (from the previous question you posted) then you don't want to use TabHost, TabManager.  You'll want to do Tabs the way 3.0+ does them using Fragments.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java

Comment: My tabs are at the bottom. Even then it wouldn't work? All i want is a standard navigation bar at the bottom (as tabs) and an actionbar at the top which tells you what page you're on and a button for an entry just like a twitter app.

Comment: Actionbar sherlock *I think* can do tabs at the bottom.  Check their demos.